# Scala elegant way to convert a multiple optional objects to a different object if at least one of the objects defined

Tags: scala

The trivial approach (with `if`,`else`), is known.
I'm thinking about how Scala can help me to do it in a more elegant way:

```
    def prepareData(baseObj: BaseObj): Option[NextObj] = {
      val maybeDataOne = Option(baseObj.getDataOne)
      val maybeDataTwo = Option(baseObj.getDataTwo)

      // return None if no DataOne or DataTwo defined
      // return Some(NextObj) if at least one of the Datas defined.

      // trivial solution:
      if(maybeDataOne.isDefined || maybeDataTwo.isDefined) {
        Some(NextObj(
          dataOne = baseObj.dataOne,
          dataTwo = baseObj.dataTwo
        ))
      } else None
    }

    //DataOne and DataTwo will be mapped to NextObj, if, at least one, is defined
    case class NextObj(d1: Option[DataOne], d2: Option[DataTwo])
```

Comment: An option of an object whose fields are options feels weird, maybe an `Option[Either[DataOne, DataTwo]]` would be better? Or maybe `Ior` from **cats**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez both could appear, and if at least one would appear, it would create `NextObj` and be mapped to it.

Comment: Look to **cats** `Ior` or if you do not want to pull out **cats** just for this, you may define your own datastructure.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think, he just _did_ define his own data structure (the one that you said felt weird) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   maybeDataOne orElse maybeDataTwo map { _ => nextObj }
```

One way to make this look even prettier is to equip your `NextObject` class with a `.toOption` method:

```
def toOption = d1 orElse d2 map { _ => this }
```

Then you can just write `NextObject(maybeDataOe, maybeDataTwo).toOption` at the call site.

Or maybe this:

```
   object NextObject {
       def opt(d1: Option[DataOne], d2: Option[DataTwo]) = 
          d1 orElse d2 map { _ => apply(d1, d2) }
   }
```

and then just `NextObject.opt(maybeDataOne, maybeDataTwo)`

Comment: Sorry, added more info.

Comment: @Johnny nothing to be sorry about, your new info doesn't really change anything – just replace `nextObj` in my snippet with `NextObj(maybeDataOne, maybeDataTwo)`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.